# how to duplicate tab but maintain scroll position of web page

Tags: browser, tabs, scrolling, duplicate

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive has code samples.

In each code example, there is a button (Edit in Plunker) that navigates the browser to a different site (Plunker). On that site I can play with the example; but it opens in the same tab. And when I hit the back button in order to return to the section I was reading, I am brought back to the very beginning of that page, and I've to scroll down to that section everytime.

My temporary workaround, on google chrome, for instance. I duplicate the tab (right-click > Duplicate Tab), scroll to that section and hit the above button. Now I can go back to my previous tab and resume reading from where I stopped.

What I am looking for is an enhanced duplicate tab feature: when I attempt to duplicate my tab, it should make note of that scroll position, and scroll the newly spawned tab to that exact position.

Comment: Tab duplication in Chrome works for me, when duplicate I go to the duplicated tab, and scroll just one time and it gets me to position of tab I've duplicated. I don't see the problem, it's not that annoying. On superuser for example it duplicates just fine :)

Comment: The code shows it calls a JS function, called `openPlunkr()` - potentially you could find out what that does, and then use something like greasemonkey (for Firefox) to change the behavior

Answer (score 0):

The better solution in Mac OS is adding a keyboard shortcut for applications. There is no need for adding an extension and no two step process

I have used 'control+g' as shortcut for duplicate tab in Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Reason for using control+g is that this combination is not used anywhere as mac os keyboard shortcut Screem shot from my mac

> System Preferences-> Keyboard -> App Shortcuts (on left panel) -> Click '+' for adding new app shortcut-> Select 'Google Chrome'
>   [image]